# Modal Pop up not loading, only background goes fade

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, popup, bootstrap-modal

The following code shown error while clicking. When clicking on the project image no pop up is loading and only the background goes fade. is there any method to overcome this error?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/slider.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link href="css/media.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/owl.carousel.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/owl.theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/demo.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/set1.css" />


<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and     `enter code here`media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>


    <div class="item">
      <div class="grid">
        <figure class="effect-bubba"> <img src="admin_flameco/project/<?php echo $prow['Image']; ?>" class="img-responsive" alt="img16"/>
          <figcaption>
            <h4 class="carous-style-text"><?php echo $prow['Text']; ?><br>
              <?php echo $prow['Text2']; ?></h4>
            <p class="carous-zoom"><i class="fa fa-search-plus carous-zoom-icon" aria-hidden="true"></i> </p>
            <h4 class="carous-text-2"><?php echo $prow['Text3']; ?></h4>
            <a href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">View more</a> </figcaption>
        </figure>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Here the pop up button. and the code as follows. the error is in this portion.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) --> 
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed --> 
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
<script>
    $(function(){
    $(".dropdown").hover(            
            function() {
                $('.dropdown-menu', this).stop( true, true ).fadeIn("fast");
                $(this).toggleClass('open');
                $('b', this).toggleClass("caret caret-up");                
            },
            function() {
                $('.dropdown-menu', this).stop( true, true ).fadeOut("fast");
                $(this).toggleClass('open');
                $('b', this).toggleClass("caret caret-up");                
            });
    }); 
</script> 
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {   
           var sideslider = $('[data-toggle=collapse-side]');
           var sel = sideslider.attr('data-target');
           var sel2 = sideslider.attr('data-target-2');
           sideslider.click(function(event){
               $(sel).toggleClass('in');
               $(sel2).toggleClass('out');
           });
var size = $(".Modern-Slider .item").size();
$("#slider-total").html(size > 10 ? size : '0' + size);
$("#current-slide").html(01);
       });
 </script> 
<script src="js/slick.js"></script> 
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){

 $(".Modern-Slider").slick({
   autoplay:true,
   autoplaySpeed:10000,
   speed:600,
   slidesToShow:1,
   slidesToScroll:1,
   pauseOnHover:false,
   dots:true,
   pauseOnDotsHover:true,
   cssEase:'linear',
  // fade:true,
   draggable:false,
   prevArrow:'<button class="PrevArrow"><span class="slider-arrow">&nbsp;PREV</span></button>',
   nextArrow:'<button class="NextArrow"><span class="slider-arrow">NEXT&nbsp;</span></button>', 
 });


 $('.Modern-Slider').on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){
var size = currentSlide + 1;
$("#current-slide").html(size > 10 ? size : '0' + size);
 })

})
 </script> 
<script src="js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script> 




<script>

    $(document).ready(function($) {
      $("#owl-example").owlCarousel({
          //Autoplay
    items : 5,
    itemsMobile : [479,2],
    itemsTablet: [768,3],
    autoPlay : false,
    stopOnHover : false,
      // Navigation
navigation : true,
 navigationText : ["<arrow>PREV</arrow>","<arrow2>NEXT</arrow2>"],
    rewindNav : true,
    scrollPerPage : false,
              pagination : false,
    paginationNumbers: false,
          //Basic Speeds
    slideSpeed : 200,
    paginationSpeed : 800,
    rewindSpeed : 1000,


          });
   });<!-- for slider -->


    $("body").data("page", "frontpage");

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i test your code in chrome .Worked.!!

Answer (score 0):

friend please check your another jquery plugins.i think you added jquery carousel occur for your issue.please remove that jquery plugins and normally check it.i think it's works fine.because that jquery or css files inherit for your bootstrap files.